# git push using PuTTY on Windows fails (fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly)

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin, putty, sshd

Excited about being ready to do my first `git push` ever, I created an alias for `PuTTY` in my cygwin environment:

```
alias ssh="/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/putty/PUTTY.EXE"
```

Then invoked (inside my working directory, of course), just as explained in page 47 in the [git community book](http://book.git-scm.com/):

```
git push ssh://mylinuxserver/~winwin/gitrepo master:master
```

My excitement didn't last very long, as it immediately failed with a fatal error:

```
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

Considering that I am able to run successfully, *from the same exact command line and shell instance*, `ssh winwin@mylinuxserver` I am very surprised to receive this error message.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?

**UPDATE I:** Thanks to [this guide](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html), I discovered that PUTTY.EXE is not the correct exe to use in git. Instead, one should be using **PLINK.EXE**.

That guide also hints that an environment variable, named GIT_SSH, should be used to let git know how to do the magic. So, I:

```
~/sb/ws> export GIT_SSH=/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/putty/PLINK.EXE
~/sb/ws> git push ssh://mylinuxserver/~winwin/gitrepo master:master
```

And now I am receiving a different error:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I consider this progress in the right direction but I still don't know how to solve the problem. Any idea would be very appreciated.

**UPDATE II:** Still trying to troubleshoot this mystery. This time I suspected that since `git push` doesn't prompt for username+password anywhere, authentication must lie within the keys... So, I double-checked `sshd` configuration per [this howto](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/ssh-with-keys/). The only thing I found as needing change was uncommenting the line `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarting the service `service sshd restart`. The first time after that, `$GIT_SSH` did prompt for confirming the server's dss key fingerprint and I confirmed storing the key in cache, but... The problem still persists:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Additional ideas?

(PuTTY's registry now contain two keys for the same server: `rsa2@22:mylinuxserver` and `dss@22:mylinuxserver`. Hmmm... I am not sure what this means)

**More diagnostic info:** Typing `$GIT_SSH -v` yields:

```
~/sb/ws> $GIT_SSH -v
Looking up host "mylinuxserver"
Connecting to 192.168.1.2 port 22
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.60
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-dss 1024 c8:77:42:4f:76:29:56:4c:ea:b0:11:6a:a6:3c:6a:f7
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
login as: winwin
winwin@mylinuxserver's password:
Sent password
Access granted
Opened channel for session
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command
Last login: Wed Jul 13 21:41:12 2011 from winmachine
```

Can you spot anything suspicious?

**Getting there:** By far the best guide for my situation: [Git, SSH, PuTTY](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/05/06/git-ssh-putty-github-unfuddle-the-kitchen-sink.aspx).

Insights:

1. `$GIT_SSH -agent` must be run once
2. PAGEANT.EXE must be running in the background (and private key added to it via its **systray icon**!)
3. PUTTYGEN.EXE must be used to generate a public/private keys pair
4. dss not mandatory, rsa is good enough.
5. [More](https://nmi.cs.wisc.edu/node/1434)? (unless `$GIT_SSH -2 -C -i C:\\Users\\winwin\\SSH\\private.ppk` succeeds without password prompt, there is no point to even try `git push`...)

After copying & pasting the public key from PuTTY Key Generator to `/home/winwin/.ssh/authorized_keys` in `mylinuxserver` a new message showed up in response to the command in insight #5 above:

```
Server refused our key
```

This is a good sign... :) I think I am on my way to solving the mystery.

**UPDATE III:** After changing `StrictModes` to **no** in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the sshd server, I managed to succeed with `$GIT_SSH -2 -C -i C:\\Users\\winwin\\SSH\\private.ppk`. It still prompts for the username, though (but doesn't prompt for password).

`git push ssh://mylinuxserver/~winwin/gitrepo master:master` continues to fail however -- with the same error message:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is insane.

**UPDATE IV:** The `-l username` parameter to PLINK is key. I managed to make `git push` login successfully, by creating a 1-line shell script `/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/putty/PLINK.EXE -l winwin $*` and exporting the the entire script's path to `$GIT_SSH`, but "the remote end still hangs up unexpectedly".

This is what I am getting on the client (Windows/PuTTY) side:

```
~/sb/ws> git push ssh://mylinuxserver/~winwin/gitrepo master:master
Environment:
  USER=winwin
  LOGNAME=winwin
  HOME=/home/winwin
  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
  MAIL=/var/mail/winwin
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.8 50951 22
  SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.8 50951 192.168.14.2 22
bash: mylinuxserver: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And This is what I am getting on the server side (Linux/sshd) side:

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_4.2p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe -1 sock 7
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.8 port 50951
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version PuTTY_Release_0.60
debug1: no match: PuTTY_Release_0.60
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.2
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST_OLD received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done

debug1: userauth-request for user winwin service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "winwin"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "win7client"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Failed none for winwin from 192.168.1.8 port 50951 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user winwin service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 1
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 513/513 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/winwin/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: matching key found: file /home/winwin/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: bd:a6:4a:6a:04:43:8d:60:d9:bf:66:de:51:13:83:66
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for winwin from 192.168.1.8 port 50951 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user winwin service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 513/513 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/winwin/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: matching key found: file /home/winwin/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: bd:a6:4a:6a:04:43:8d:60:d9:bf:66:de:51:13:83:66
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted publickey for winwin from 192.168.1.8 port 50951 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: winwin has been authenticated by privileged process
Accepted publickey for winwin from 192.168.1.8 port 50951 ssh2
debug1: PAM: reinitializing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 513/513
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 256 win 16384 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug1: session_new: init
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request exec reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req exec
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
debug1: session_by_pid: pid 3441
debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 3441
debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
debug1: session_close: session 0 pid 3441
debug1: channel 0: free: server-session, nchannels 1

Connection closed by 192.168.1.8
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
Closing connection to 192.168.1.8
debug1: PAM: cleanup
```

Last clue needed...

1. What does `bash: mylinuxserver: command not found` mean?
2. What is `git push` trying to run?
3. Which command?
4. On the client or the SSH server?

Comment: Can you create a symlink from PuTTY to ssh.exe?

Comment: @Ben Hocking Yes I can, but see my update above. Thanks +1.

Comment: Why don't you just use "real" ssh, i.e. Cygwin's openssh package?

Comment: @ak2 Good idea. I must solve this mystery first, though, before installing Cygwin's openssh (it didn't come with core Cygwin by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never succeeded making `git` work with `PuTTY`. Further time investment on my side didn't seem to justify ROI, so I am giving up.

Answer (score 2):

using plink? you might have to recreate the keys which you created for putty.

http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/156/

Comment: Yes, I am using PLINK.EXE. See my update earlier. Thanks +1 for the link. My `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` contains the correct keys but `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` have **none** for some reason. I will try that and report back.

Comment: OK, done with replicating the keys to `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` but I still get the `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` error. I suspect that's because PLINK tries to connect by default to a **different host**. How do I change that?

Comment: OK, the problem of connecting to a different host [has been solved](http://superuser.com/questions/310181/plink-is-stuck-at-an-older-host-how-do-i-replace-it/310207#310207). But the error `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` persists. How do I find why?

Comment: Have you looked at git documentation? https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Git_push_fails_with_.22fatal:_The_remote_end_hung_up_unexpectedly.22.3F

Comment: Which git documentation? :) There are so [many of them](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)... Anyway, thanks +1 for the link to the FAQ. I checked and verified that: (1) I'm using ssh URL. (2) The aforementioned user account has write permissions to `~winwin/gitrepo` at `mylinuxserver`. (3) The public keys are most likely installed OK because I can ssh from the command line without any problem. Any other ideas? Is it possible that the public keys are OK for $GIT_SSH (prompts for username & password) but not for `git push` which uses exactly the same $GIT_SSH?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like going through Putty is what's creating all of these issues but it's not clear why that's necessary - if you're using cygwin then you already have ssh built in.

I use git through cygwin over ssh with no issues.  Might be a better route?  Was there a reason for incorporating putty or was it something that was recommended in a guide somewhere?

Comment: I agree. On the other hand, going through this exercise in futility helped me learn things what I would never have learned otherwise.