# Is the result of git push 100% protocol neutral?

Tags: git, git-push

After unsuccessfully trying to `git push` [using ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681918/git-push-using-putty-on-windows-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly), I am ready to give up and just use plain filesystem push (fortunately, that linux server has Samba running on it as well).

Before switching git transports, I was wondering: Is the result of `git push` always the same regardless of the protocol used? Including owner, chmod, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is neutral, but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071241/how-does-git-handle-folder-permission/1071274#1071274) for what file info is tracked.  To sum it up, users/groups/permissions aren't tracked.  What if you cloned the repo to a computer that didn't have that user.