# Problem with Jenkins accessing Mercurial repository on bitbucket.org

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, bitbucket

My Jenkins server has stopped being able to build a maven project hosted at bitbucket.org. The build works locally but Jenkins reports this error:

```
[workspace] $ hg incoming --quiet --bundle hg.bundle --template "<changeset node='{node}' author='{author|xmlescape}' rev='{rev}' date='{date}'><msg>{desc|xmlescape}</msg><added>{file_adds|stringify|xmlescape}</added><deleted>{file_dels|stringify|xmlescape}</deleted><files>{files|stringify|xmlescape}</files><parents>{parents}</parents></changeset>\n" --rev default
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
ERROR: Failed to determine incoming changes
[workspace] $ hg log --rev . --template {node}
```

Any ideas what's going on?

[edit]

So, I ran `hg paths` and got a response that the tomcat user was untrusted:

```
Not trusting file /usr/local/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/Test/workspace/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user tomcat, group tomcat
```

After running `hg incoming` as the tomcat user

```
cd /usr/local/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/Test/workspace
sudo -u tomcat hg incoming
```

I got an error saying the permissions on my ssh key were too open:

```
remote: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
remote: @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
remote: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
remote: Permissions 0620 for '/usr/local/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
remote: It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
remote: This private key will be ignored.
remote: bad permissions: ignore key: /usr/local/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

and thanks [to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556119/ssh-private-key-permissions-using-git-gui-or-ssh-keygen-are-too-open)

I set the permissions and now Jenkins can successfully build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `hg incoming` is based on whatever your 'default' path is in the repository's `hgrc` (use `hg paths` to see them, or open the file), maybe you should make sure the address of the remote repository is still correct and that the project is still accessible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer as it did lead me to a solution.

Comment: That's all I was trying to do, since I didn't have access to the information you discovered in the process.

Comment: @Industrial: Everything after "edit" in his post is how he fixed it.

Comment: Sorry, was to tired to notice that :) Thanks for the heads up!