# gitolite-admin and gitolite server on same machine

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

There's a somewhat similar question here, but it didn't solve my problem, so gere's the deal. I've created a  gitolite server on my secundar machine, but I'm also hosting a web service there. My intention is that the web service can communicate with it, for exemple, add a new repository. For that, I need to clone the gitolite-admin repository to the same machine where the server is hosted.

So, I've created the user 'git', that is in charge of the gitolite server. I've tried generate ssh-key pair and copied to my primary machine so I could add it to the users on the gitolite-admin repository.

But, on the secondary machine, where the server is hosted, with a user different from 'git', when I try to git clone git@localhost:gitolite-admin, it says:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/home/pi/.ssh/raspi.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /home/pi/.ssh/raspi.pub
git@localhost's password:
```

And I disabled the 'git' password but it still asks for it. Please, help me here.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/1556119/6309 help?

Comment: It seems it's not much problem with `Git` as it's problem with `SSH`. A public key should have `-rw-r--r-- ` permissions, make sure it does.

Comment: VonC, sorry bit it didn't help...
 Arkadiusz Drabczyk, yes, it does have -rw-r--r-- permissions.