# OpenSSH on Windows require password despite ssh-copy-id

Tags: ssh, openssh, openssh-for-windows

After using Git Bash and do the `ssh-copy-id` to my linux box, it works well, in Git Bash Windows, I can happily do `ssh -p {PORT} {ME}@{MY_SERVER}` and enjoy my server

but when I use the OpenSSH built-in from PowerShell, it require me to input password

**How to make OpenSSH_for_Windows "know" that I have set passwordless login?**

I'm using `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2` on `Windows 10 Ver 22H2`

Note:

1. I've checked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4484/ssh-prompts-for-password-despite-ssh-copy-id) on Unix Stackexchange but it's not fit with my problem (I'm using Windows)
2. I've check the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560807/373266) but it doesn't work

[image: Git bash can do ssh without password, OpenSSH on Powershell not]